# Javascript concat string from multiple array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

```
    var colDisp = {

    "COL1": [

        [
            {
                'id': 'select1Opt1',
                'txt': 'A'
            },
            {
                'id': 'select1Opt2',
                'txt': 'B'
            }


        ],

        [
            {
                'id': 'textbox1',
                'txt': 'C'
            }

        ],

        [
            {
                'id': 'select2Opt1',
                'txt': 'D'
            },
            {
                'id': 'select2Opt2',
                'txt': 'E'
            }
        ]

    ],
    "COL2": [
        [
            {
                'id': 'select3Opt1',
                'txt': 'F'
            },
            {
                'id': 'select3Opt2',
                'txt': 'G'
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                'id': 'textbox2',
                'txt': 'H'
            }
        ]

    ]
}


var outPut = [
  'COL1:select1Opt1-textbox1-select2Opt1|||COL2:select3Opt1-textbox2',
  'COL1:select1Opt1-textbox1-select2Opt2|||COL2:select3Opt1-textbox2',
  'COL1:select1Opt2-textbox1-select2Opt1|||COL2:select3Opt1-textbox2',
  'COL1:select1Opt2-textbox1-select2Opt2|||COL2:select3Opt1-textbox2',

]

var makeOtpDocPick = function(colDisp){
    var lst = {}, lstColItm = [], col;
    for(var colName in colDisp){
        col = colDisp[colName];
        lst[colName] = [];
        console.log(colName);
        var frist = col[0];// it is array 
        frist.forEach(function(fItem){
            var fItmTmp = fItem.id;

            col.forEach(function(v, idx){
                if(idx == 0) return true;

                v.forEach(function(_v){

                    lstColItm = [];
                    lstColItm.push(fItmTmp);

                    var tmp = _v.id
                    lstColItm.push(tmp);

                    var colVal = lstColItm.join('-');
                    lst[colName].push(colVal);
                });

            });

        });

    }

    console.log(lst);
};

makeOtpDocPick(colDisp);
```

I have any section (they are COL1 and COL2 in my example), in every section I have 2 (or more than) documents.
In every document will have any input field (textbox, selectbox).
Textbox have only one value, selectbox will have list option value.

I want to concat id from all section but id's of one option (select box) shouldn't be duplicated.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: please explain the logic. How they should be sorted?

Comment: i can send you hard coded version, but i don't think that is good way, so to make code dynamic please explain the logic

Comment: i have update example in here: http://jsfiddle.net/thinhnk/yqzqgcqL/1/

i have any section (they are COL1 and COL2 in my example), in every section i have 2 (or more than) documents.
In every document will have any input field (textbox, selectbox).
Textbox have onle one value, selectbox will have list option value.

i want to concat id from all section but id of one option (select box) not duplicate.

Sorry for my english good.

Comment: Put your code here, not just in a fiddle link.